# Alternate Solution for maxBlock from CodingBat

Tags: java

Solving [this problem](http://codingbat.com/prob/p179479) from codingBat

> Given a string, return the length of the largest "block" in the
>   string. A block is a run of adjacent chars that are the same.
>
> `maxBlock("hoopla") → 2`
>   `maxBlock("abbCCCddBBBxx") → 3`
>   `maxBlock("") → 0`

I was trying to solve it using one for loop as below:

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
  int maxCounter=1;
  int counter=1;
  if(str.length()==0)
  {
    return 0;
  }  
  for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++)
  {
    if(str.substring(i,i+1).equals(str.substring(i+1,i+2)))
    {
      counter++;

    }   
    if(counter>maxCounter)
    {
      maxCounter=counter;
      counter=0;
    }            
  }  


  return maxCounter;          
}
```

It beats all the cases apart from one. Can anybody show a solution with one for loop?

Sorry for mentioning late but you can't use REGEX or anything from collections framework.

Comment: "*It beats all the cases apart from one*" > What does this mean?

Comment: Well what case does it fail on?

Comment: @Duncan maxBlock("XXBBBBbbxx") should return 4 but it's returning 3 with my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get it wrong in certain edge cases:

```
public int yourMaxBlock(String str) {
    int maxCounter = 1;
    int counter = 1;
    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.substring(i, i + 1).equals(str.substring(i + 1, i + 2))) {
            counter++;

        }
        if (counter > maxCounter) {
            maxCounter = counter;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }

    return maxCounter;
}

public int myMaxBlock(String str) {
    int maxCounter = 1;
    int counter = 1;
    if (str.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i - 1) == str.charAt(i)) {
            if (++counter > maxCounter) {
                maxCounter = counter;
            }
        } else {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }

    return maxCounter;
}

public void test() {
    String[] tests = new String[]{
        "", "+", "++", "+++,++,++,+", "+,++,+++,++,", "+,++,+++,++++", "+++++,++,+++,++++"
    };
    for (String s : tests) {
        int myMax = myMaxBlock(s);
        int yourMax = yourMaxBlock(s);
        System.out.println("myMaxBlock(" + s + ") = " + myMax + (myMax != yourMax ? " WRONG! you have " + yourMax : ""));
    }
}
```

prints

```
myMaxBlock() = 0
myMaxBlock(+) = 1
myMaxBlock(++) = 2
myMaxBlock(+++,++,++,+) = 3
myMaxBlock(+,++,+++,++,) = 3
myMaxBlock(+,++,+++,++++) = 4 WRONG! you have 3
myMaxBlock(+++++,++,+++,++++) = 5 WRONG! you have 4
```

Comment: Thanks @OldCurmudgeon I saw your solutions little late but nice work...you about neatly corrected what I was missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Pattern matcher `"(.)(\\1)*"` that look for repeated char in the String , Here is the code :

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.)(\\1)*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
        int max = 0;
        while (matcher.find()) {
            max = Math.max(max, matcher.group().length());
        }
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really address a question that ends "*Can anybody show a solution with one for loop?*". Although still a useful answer.

Comment: That wasn't mentioned before

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but here's my CodingBat solution:

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
    int max = 0;
    int count = 1;
    char o = ' ';

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if (c == o) {
            count++;
            if (count > max) { max = count; }
        } else {
            count = 1;
            if (count > max) { max = count; }
        }
        o = c;     
    }

    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution based loosely on yours. Note the use of `charAt` for a neater looking code example.

This starts at the second character of the string and looks backwards to see if we are still encountering the same character. If so, the counter increases. When we finish a string of identical chars, we compare against the max length found thus far and update if necessary.

```
public static int maxBlock(String str) {
    int maxCounter = 1;
    int counter = 1;

    if (str.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i - 1) == str.charAt(i)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            // end of a run
            if (counter > maxCounter) {
                maxCounter = counter;
            }

            counter = 1;
        }

    }

    return Math.max(maxCounter, counter);
}
```

Comment: Not working in case maxBlock("xyzz") it should return 2 but returning 1 instead

Comment: @Anirudh Good point - couple of adjustments made above. This now passes the test on that web page.

Comment: @Anirudh OldCurmudgeon's answer is neater. My `Math.max` bit was just a quick hack :-)

Comment: Yeah..there is actually no need to use 2 loops here..simple codes are more efficient :-]

Answer (score 0):

Just use one for loop. I think here is another way.

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
  int len = str.length();
  int temp=(len>0)?1:0;
  int r =0;

  for(int i=1; i<len; i++){   
    if(str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i-1)){
      temp++;   
    }
    else{
      r = (temp>r)?temp:r;
      temp=1;
    }
  }
  r = (temp>r)?temp:r;
  return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {

    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i ++ ) {
       char compareChar = str.charAt(i);
       int count = 0;
       while (i + 1 < str.length() 
              && compareChar == str.charAt(i+1)) {
           i++;
           count ++;
      } 

      if (max < count + 1) {
         max = count + 1;
      }
   }
   return max;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It's simpler than you think.

```
public int maxBlock(String str) 
{
    //create a counter to return
    int counter = 0;
    //create a temporary variable to store a running total.
    int temp = 1;
    //Start on the first character and test to see if the second
    //character equals the first.
    for (int i = 1; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
      //If it does, we increment the temp variable.
      if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i-1))
      {
        temp++;
      }
      //If it doesn't, we wipe the temp variable and start from one.
      else
      {
        temp = 1;
      }
      //If the temporary variable exceeds the counter amount, we make
      //the counter variable equal to the temp variable.
      if (temp > counter)
      {
        counter = temp;
      }
    }
    //Return the counter.
    return counter;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
int maxLength = 0;
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i< str.length(); i++){
String key = str.substring(i,i+1);
if(i!=0 && str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i-1) && map.containsKey(key)){
map.put(key, map.get(key)+1);
}
else{
map.put(key,1);
}
}

for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()){
if(maxLength <entry.getValue()){
maxLength = entry.getValue();
}
}

return maxLength;
}
```

Comment: Please edit that post so that it shows up as code, and add a description of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {

    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int maxcount = 0;
    if (str.length() == 0) return 0;

    while (i < str.length() - 1) {

        if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(i + 1)) {

            count++;

            if (count > maxcount) {
                maxcount = count;
            }
        } else count = 0;

        i++;
    }

    return maxcount + 1;
}
```

Comment: Here you go with one loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int maxBlock(String str) {
  int tcount = 0;
  if (str.length() < 1) {
    return 0;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = i; j < str.length(); j++) {
      if (str.charAt(i) == str.charAt(j)) {
        count++;
      } else
        break;
    }
    if (count > tcount) {
      tcount = count;
    }
    i += count - 1;

  }
  return tcount;
}
```

this is easier it totally works.

Answer (score -1):

```
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

while(i < inner.length && j < outer.length) {
        if(inner[i] > outer[j]) {
            j++;
        } else if(inner[i] < outer[j]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if(i != inner.length)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here My code for this

```
 public int maxBlock(String str) {

  int count = 1;
  for(int i=0;i<str.length()-1;i++){
     int count2 = 0;

     if(str.substring(i,i+1).equals(str.substring(i+1,i+2) )){
       for(int j = i ; j < str.length();j++){
          if(str.substring(i,i+1).equals(str.substring(j,j+1))){
            ++count2;
          }
          else{
            break;
          }
       }
     }

     if(count2 > count){
       count = count2;
     }


  }

  if(str.isEmpty())return 0;
  return count;
}
```

Comment: Please next time use comments to explain your code. Refer to this in your next answers : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer